# How to open a small box from a web page to make a choice

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am really new with javascript, html, and css and am currently in the process of creating a game web application. I would like to be able to have kind of a pop up box when you click on a card the appears in the middle of the screen showing the options that you can click for that card (meanwhile the main page colors get darker) and when you select one of those options it goes away (Or if you click off of the popup).

I'm not sure if I'm explaining it very well, but I don't even know what to look up online because I don't know what that is called or even where to start with that. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean a [modal window](http://simplemodal.plasm.it/)?

Comment: Yes! This is it, that is what I was looking for. I'd like to program it on my own however, any tips to where to start with my javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a div in your html and a :

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="card"></div>
```

give the diff a background color using rgba to enable transparency and the default display value set to none and give it 100% width and height:

```
#test {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: none;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
```

Then in javascript u can use an event listener on click to trigger change the display state to block:

```
document.getElementById("card").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.display = "block";
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle so you can check it out: [click](https://jsfiddle.net/rot1obb8/)